# Joint Continuity of the Lebesgue Integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

This is exercise **131Xb** $(iii)$ from Fremlin Volume 1:

Show that if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, then $(a,b)\mapsto\int_a^b f d\mu$ is continuous. ( *Hint:* Either consider simple functions $f$ first or consider $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a_n}^b f d\mu$ for monotonic sequences $(a_n)$ ).

Here is my work so far:

Since $f$ is integrable $\int_a^b f d\mu=\int f\chi_{(a,b)} d\mu$ is well-defined in $\mathbb{R}$ for any pair $(a,b)$. Let $a_n \downarrow a$. Then $f\chi_{(a_n,b)}\to f\chi_{(a,b)}$ pointwise. Moreover, $\lvert f\chi_{(a_n,b)}\rvert \leq \lvert f \rvert$ for all $n$, and $\lvert f \rvert$ is integrable because $f$ is. Hence we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem to get $\int_a^b f d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a_n}^b f d\mu$. Since $(a_n)$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $a\mapsto\int_a^b f d\mu$ is continuous from the right. Considering increasing sequences $a_n \uparrow a$ we get $a\mapsto\int_a^b f d\mu$ continuous from the left, and so the map $a\mapsto\int_a^b f d\mu$ is continuous for any $b$. A similar argument shows that $b\mapsto\int_a^b f d\mu$ is continuous for any $a$.

**Questions:**

$(1)$ How can I show joint continuity with respect to $(a,b)$?

$(2)$ The hint suggests to use monotonic sequences, but why? It seems that considering an arbitrary sequence $a_n\to a$ would do the job, and in fact would cut the proof in half.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something subtle, you can apply your same argument to the functions $f\chi_{(a_n,b_n)}$, where $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$, to obtain the full result in one step. I don't see why the author suggests to consider monotone sequences or to vary only one endpoint. Does this exercise perhaps cover material that does not yet assume the DCT?

Comment: @Bungo At this point in the book we have covered the DCT.

Comment: The only subtlety I can think of is that $\chi_{(a_n,b_n)}$ may not converge at the the endpoints $a$ and $b$. Consider, e.g., $a_n = a + (-1)^n/n$ and $b_n = b + (-1)^n/n$. So $\chi_{(a_n,b_n)}$ may not converge pointwise at those two points. But it converges everywhere else to $\chi_{(a,b)}$, and a.e. convergence is all we need for DCT.

Comment: @Bungo Right! It also seems like using a joint sequence $(a_n,b_n)$ is the only way to prove joint continuity. Otherwise you only get continuity in one variable. But then am totally confused about the hint...

Comment: Well, $\int_{a_n}^{b_n} = \int_{a_n}^{a} + \int_{b}^{b_n} +  \int_{a}^{b}$, so you're trying to show that the first two integrals on the RHS converge to zero as $(a_n,b_n) \to (a,b)$. The first integral depends only on $a_n$, not $b_n$, and similarly the second integral depends only on $b_n$, not $a_n$. So there's no dependence on the specific path along which $(a_n,b_n)$ converges to $(a,b)$. And $(a_n,b_n) \to (a,b)$ iff $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$. So it suffices to handle $a_n$ and $b_n$ separately. But there's also no reason to do so.

Comment: @Bungo OK. Still, monotonicity seems irrelevant.

Comment: I agree. The only thing I can think of that monotonicity buys you is that you either approach from the left or from the right, in both of which cases $\lim \chi_{(a_n,b_n)}$ exists pointwise everywhere, even at $a$ and $b$. But as I commented earlier, you don't need convergence everywhere to apply the DCT. Convergence almost everywhere suffices. Aside from this I have no idea why the author is suggesting to look at monotone sequences.